# Update a JList at run time

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

How would I update a `JList` while the program is running? I'm importing a an `ArrayList` from another class, and putting it into the list. I'm to make it when the user adds something to the array list it will appear in the list on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the `ArrayList` in some kind of `ListModel` and change the `JList`'s model by using `JList#setModel`

See [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

You could use a `DefaultListModel`, whenever you update the `ArrayList`, you would need to update the `DefaultListModel` but using something like [`add(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#add%28int,%20E%29), [`addElement(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement%28E%29), [`remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#remove%28int%29), [`removeElement(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#removeElement%28java.lang.Object%29) or [`removeAllElements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#removeAllElements%28%29) based on your needs.

This will automatically notify the `JList` of changes to made to the model

**Updated**

A more complex approach might be to use a proxy pattern, where by you create an `ArrayList` proxy which provides information about when it changes which can be reflected in the automatically model.  This assumes that the class you are importing the `ArrayList` from asks your class for an instance of the the `ArrayList`.

This way you could monitor the `add`, `set` and `remove` methods and make changes to the `ListModel` automatically...

Comment: You don't even need to use `setModel`, you could just change the model.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg It will depend on whether you want to remove the elements from the original list or not.  It will also depend on whether you want to merge the two lists or not. Personally, quicker to create a new list. But not enough information to say one way or other...

Comment: *"But not enough information to say one way or other.."* from the OP  Edited) *"when the user adds something to the array list it will appear in the list on the screen."*   Seems pretty clear that way.  Wonder if it is a correct interpritation?  --  I was thinking maybe a [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) with methods like [`addElement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement%28E%29).. (would be best here)

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's probably more to do with being half a sleep